# What is the best method for carrying a 4x8 by yourself over tough terrain?

Tags: wood, tools

I have to travel about a quarter mile through the wilderness, carrying a 4x8 each time to get to a remote building location. Some of the terrain can be tricky, otherwise I might fall in the water. Any ideas on the best way to carry a 4x8 panel?

I am imagining a clever backpack contraption.

Are there any tools, strategies, or methods one can recommend for achieving this?

Comment: First, one 2x8 and a sack of 10d nails. Then another 2x8 and a tube of construction adhesive. Perhaps a hammer if suitable rocks are not available.

Comment: Panel handles = http://www.lowes.com/pd_86688-61896-86688_0__?productId=3727645 , personally I just use gloves, these things are silly.

Comment: After a 1\4 mile I might change my position about how stupid they are.

Comment: Heh; well the other challenge is hauling these things on a bike.

Comment: There are bike trailers which can be equipped with brackets to hold a plywood panel almost-vertically, 8' edge down. Would almost certainly NOT work over rough terrain, though.

Comment: Wheelbarrows go over moderately rough terrain.   If you have a good-size wheelbarrow handy, I would try strapping the 4x8 to it.

Comment: Do they have wheelbarrows specifically tailored for 4x8 panels?

Comment: There are panel carts, but they are for moving panels across a yard or construction site, not the wilderness.  http://www.amazonsupply.com/dp/B001B4TMUI?ref_=sr_4_17_txt&filterBy.enc-merchantbin=A2LPUKX2E7NPQV or this: http://www.amazonsupply.com/dp/B0000224PA/ref=pd_sim_0

Comment: Are you talking 4'x8' panels? Or 4"x8" beams?

Comment: Panels. Beams are more manageable.

Comment: A big quadcopter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a low-tech method that's worked well for me:

[image]

Attach a loop of rope around the bottom corners and pull it up in the middle on the outside with your arm going over it and your other arm holding it stable in your armpit.

Comment: Can you enter a description?  Sometimes the images don't come through, and the answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 4):

You might find that spending a little time and effort upgrading your 1/4 mile path, potentially even building some small bridges for the water hazards, pays large benefits in the ease of hauling materials to your building site. You could probably also customize a wheelbarrow for the panel-carrying job - ideally starting with one that needs a new pan, or else starting with a (sturdy) bicycle wheel and making it from the ground up. To carry a 4x8  foot panel effectively you want handles nearly 6 feet long, so you may need to go custom anyway. The panel can overhang the wheel a bit, but the center of the panel needs to be on the same side as the handles, and you need enough room to hold the handles and not hit your face on the panels.

I will share that single-wheel wheelbarrows are much better on a non-level (side to side) path than two-wheel versions, as you can hold the single-wheel type upright, while the two-wheel cart follows any tilt in the path, and can be more prone to tip over as a result. You should also beware of the urge to load as much as you can pick up into a wheelbarrow - it gets heavy on a 1/4 mile trip, and then you may end up dumping it before you reach the end.

Comment: The easiest way to carry the 4x8 is to bobcat a road, pour concrete and drive it there.

Comment: @DMoore plus you get to rent a bobcat!

Comment: @DA01 - bobcatting is definitely up there on the fun scale.  I seem to be an expert at digging holes but not so much on making the ground flat.